# Can I init multi database on Peewee, from main.py without proxy

Tags: python, peewee

I want to be able to create multiple files of same model database.
To use each file with it own connection.
Without the need to initialize the database each time I want to use a different one.

Something like:

```
sqlite_1.add_user(name="Jerry")
sqlite_2.add_user(name="Jerry")
```

**Solution with proxy with initialize**

main.py

```
# main.py

import peewee as pw
import database as db

sqlite_1 = pw.SqliteDatabase('sqlite_1.db')
sqlite_2 = pw.SqliteDatabase('sqlite_2.db')

db.proxy.initialize(sqlite_1)
sqlite_1.create_tables([db.User], safe=True)
db.add_user(name="Tom")

db.proxy.initialize(sqlite_2)
sqlite_2.create_tables([db.User], safe=True)
db.add_user(name="Jerry")
```

database.py:

```
# database.py
import peewee as pw

proxy = pw.Proxy()


class BaseModel(pw.Model):
  class Meta:
    database = proxy


class User(BaseModel):
  name = pw.CharField()


def add_user(name):
  with proxy.atomic() as txn:
    User.create(name=name).save()


def get_user(name):
  with proxy.atomic() as txn:
    return User.get(User.name == name)
```

Can I do multiple databased with same model without proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `bind()` and `bind_ctx()` methods to swap a model between databases at runtime:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database.bind_ctx

```
MODELS = (User, Account, Note)

# Bind the given models to the db for the duration of wrapped block.
def use_test_database(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def inner(self):
        with test_db.bind_ctx(MODELS):
            test_db.create_tables(MODELS)
            try:
                fn(self)
            finally:
                test_db.drop_tables(MODELS)
    return inner


class TestSomething(TestCase):
    @use_test_database
    def test_something(self):
        # ... models are bound to test database ...
        pass
```

Comment: I will test it soon, why is it not like sqlite that you save connection ?